# About order in indexing

Tags: indexing

In the running text I have: LaTeX `\index{subject}{\textsc{prog}}\textsc{prog}`

> **Problem**: how to get small capital PROG in the P-list rather than in front of the whole index? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what's happening here because your call to `\index` doesn't resemble the standard LaTeX `\index` command. I'm assuming you meant to write

```
\index{\textsc{prog}}
```

rather than

```
\index{subject}{\textsc{prog}}
```

so I'm going to proceed as if I'm correct.

To specify a sort key which is different than the printed index entry, you can do this with `@` in the argument to `\index` everything before `@` will be used for sorting purposes and everything after will be the actually printed index entry. In your case you would want to write

```
 \index{prog@\textsc{prog}}
```

to get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works fine!